# how can i plot a histogram of crime type vs HOURS in r

Tags: r

i have a big dataset, with diferent variables and i want to make a histogram of type of crime against HOURS. how can i do that in r?

```
        DATE  TIME                          PLACE    ZONE TYPE.OF.CRIME WEEK
1 2011/01/01 23:00 KIEPIES CLUB                      <NA> ARMED ROBBERY    1
2 2011/01/03 10:00 AUSSPANNPLATZ                  Zone 14 ARMED ROBBERY    1
3 2011/01/07 14:00 UNAM BUSHES                    Zone 16 ARMED ROBBERY    1
4 2011/01/08 21:34 TOTAL SERV. STATION, KHOMASDAL  Zone 9 ARMED ROBBERY    1
5 2011/01/15  <NA> WOODPALM STR 625               Zone 11 ARMED ROBBERY    2
6 2011/01/03 14:03 C KANDOVAZU STR                 Zone 5   ASSAULT GBH    1
  HOUR day month year HOURS
1   23   1     1 2011    23
2   10   3     1 2011    10
3   14   7     1 2011    14
4   21   8     1 2011    21
5 <NA>  15     1 2011  <NA>
6   14   3     1 2011    14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=TYPE.OF.CRIME, y=HOURS)) +
geom_histogram()
```

Something like this should work.